# How much does a program that has to talk to arbitrary servers need SSH v1 support?

Tags: ssh, libssh2, libssh

I'm starting a new project, a cross-platform C++ program that will need to connect to servers of the user's choice using SSH code built into the program. I'm trying to decide between [`libssh`](http://www.libssh.org/) and [`libssh2`](http://www.libssh2.org/). (Licensing is not an issue; `libssh`'s LGPL is fine.)

`libssh2` seems, from [this page](http://www.libssh2.org/libssh2-vs-libssh.html), to be the way to go -- with one possible exception. It doesn't support SSH v1. I have no idea what percentage of servers out there might only support SSH v1 these days. Does anyone have experience in this area, or could point me to something that would answer that?

Alternatively, can anyone point out another SSH library with SCP capability that supports both SSH v1 and v2? Preferably one that is thread-safe and can also support non-blocking operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There still exist some hardware devices which only offer SSH1, but when it comes to software, locking to SSH1 is dangerous as SSH1 has security flaws. Consequently if you don't plan to connect to hardware, omitting SSH1 completely is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

SSHv1 has already been outdated in the times when I became familiar with Linux, back in 2004. SO I don't think that many servers will support SSHv1 only nowadays.

If a server does only support v1, it is to be considered in a very bad state, IMO.